# How to calculate the effective area of a solar panel

Tags: trigonometry, spherical-trigonometry

I am working on a project where I need to model the output of solar panels during the day.
Because the sun moves across the horizon it won't always shine straight at the panels.
For this reason, I wanted to calculate the area equivalent if the panel were to point directly at the sun. For example, if the panel were to point straight up and the sun was at a zenith angle of 45deg the effective area would be $0.5\sqrt2$

I have been using a model where I calculate the difference between the azimuth and zenith angles of the sun and panels and multiplying the cos of these angles to get an area. The problem is that this breaks down the moment I use a flat panel. In the case of a flat panel the azimuth shouldn't matter, yet it does in my model, e.g.: cos(AZ*panel* - AZ*sun*) * cos(ZEN*panel* - ZEN*sun*). I have not managed to find any documentation of what formula's I should be using.

I am looking for the solution to my problem given the solar angles and panel angles. Does anybody have a model, formula, or documentation which can help me with my issue?

Thank you for reading and I hope you can help.

Comment: What do you mean "a flat panel"? Aren't they all flat?

Comment: @user619894 Yes, but what I mean with a flat panel is one on a flat surface, pointing straight up at the sky. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you call "azimuth". Is it the solar panel's orientation? It is better to define orientation by the direction $\hat n$ normal to the panel.

Comment: @user619894 the azimuth is the horizontal angle of the panel defined as 0deg when pointing north and positive to the east. e.g. 90 deg is east, 180 is south, and 270 is west.

Comment: How do you call the angle with respect to the horizon? With totally horizontal 0 ( or perhaps 90 if you prefer using the normal direction)?

Comment: @user619894 That would be the zenith, with vertical being 0deg and horizontal being 90deg. so a panel pointing straight up would have a zenith angle of 0 deg.

Comment: I am not familiar with your terminology. But euristically, what you are looking for is the scalar product between two unit vectors, the first one normal to your solar panel and the second one pointing towards the sun from the center of your solar panel. Then you multiply by it's area. Are you okay with that concept or am i just telling you something you already know ? That would be the sinus of the angle between the two described vectors times the area

Comment: I suspect something is wrong with the model. Where did is come from?

Comment: @Pastudent A colleague of mine suggested the same, I am working on that now. Perhaps the plan to use trigonometry was wrong to begin with.

Comment: @user619894 I made the model myself, thinking if I got the effective horizontal and vertical area, and multiply those I would get an effective overall area. The problem comes when the panel points straight up, at that point the horizontal rotation shouldn't matter, but it does in my model. That is where the problem lies.

Comment: To be pedantic, you are technicaly using trigonometry :) Would you count my comment as an answer ?

Comment: The product of areas is not area. The correct way to think of this (as @Pastudent wrote) is to use the direction cosine https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_cosine.

Comment: @Pastudent yeah, I think we can count your comment as an answer.

Comment: @user619894 It would appear that the problem is a bit more complex than I had originally thought. Thanks for the comments and insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Euristically, what you are looking for is the scalar product between two unit vectors, the first one normal to your solar panel and the second one pointing towards the sun from the center of your solar panel. Then you multiply by it's area.Then you multiply by it's area.
In other words $$A_{eff} = \cos(\text{angle})\times A_{\text{solar panel}}$$
The Angle being the one described above and $A$ standing for Area.

Now, if the sun is on the other side of the plane, you will get a negative effective Area. Technicaly, you should just say that the actual effective area is zero whenever get a negative number.